# In Chrome's javascript console can I call a function and then step through it?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, console

I need to debug some strange behavior with a javascript function that appears to work just fine when I run its code line by line in the console, but fails when I call the function itself.  In Chrome's javascript console, is it possible to call a function and then step through it? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds like you have an asynchronous call issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not?
Put a breakpoint on the first line of the function, or a 'debugger' statement, and then just call it ...

Comment: ah, I had a breakpoint at the line where the function is declared...I moved it one line down and now it works, thanks